# XMLHttpRequest and Unique Session ID PHP

Tags: php, ajax, session, xmlhttprequest, sessionid

i created a javascript to track users cross-domain over the Session in PHP and with it know if the user is online, in the javascript i'm using XMLHttpRequest and send by POST Method, over a function setInterval to repeat this track, it works fine to me, but for each call in XMLHttpRequest the PHP Session generate other Session ID, i want just Unique Session ID by user online.

PHP: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); //allow cross-domain request`

Javascript:

```
var __url__rastreamento = "http://external-domain.com/rastreamento/"
var __rastreamento_tempo = 10000;
var __pagina__titulo = document.title;
var __url__requisicao = document.location.href.replace(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host,"");
var __url__host = window.location.host; 

var __x__h__r;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{//IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    __x__h__r = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{//IE6, IE5
    __x__h__r = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function recarregaRastreamento(){
    __x__h__r.open("POST",__url__rastreamento ,true);
    __x__h__r.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    __x__h__r.send("titulo=" + escape(__pagina__titulo) + "&host=" +escape(__url__host) + "&requisicao=" + escape(__url__requisicao));
}

setInterval("recarregaRastreamento()", __rastreamento_tempo);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: "send by POST Method." Send what? Can we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-origin requests are not allowed with [XMLHttpRequests](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) until [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/). And if the latter is supported, you need to set the [*withCredentials* attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-withcredentials-attribute) to allow credentials being sent for cross-origin requests.